# Install the generic mapping tool (GMT) on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gmt

I am trying to use GMT on cygwin, but I am unable to do so. I followed [this link](https://wiki.canterbury.ac.nz/display/QuakeCore/How+to+install+GMT+on+Cygwin) but could not install gdal due to PROJ 6 error.

How can I use GMT functions on Cygwin

Comment: Are you aware that Cygwin already has `libgdal-devel  3.0.4-1` and `libproj-devel 6.3.1-1` ? Please report commands you are using and errors you are receiving.

Comment: I need to use gmt commands on Cygwin, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi, just downloaded it and installed it on windows, it is running on Cygwin.

Comment: the information are clearly dated as gdal 3.x is already available on Cygwin and you don't need to build by yourself. Can you please skip the gdal portion of the instruction, install libgdal-devel and libproj-devel packages, and report the outcome of the `Build and install GMT:` portion reporting commands and error ?